# Jquery TD contains some text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to detect if a `<td>` in a table contains text and change the background if it does.  I'd like to use an 'if then' if possible since there is more I want to do related to detecting the text.

```
<td class="pme-cell-WFA">Test</td>

if ($('.pme-main tr').find('td.pme-cell-WFA:not(:contains("Test"))')) {
    $('.pme-main tr').find('td.pme-cell-WFA').css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
}
else {
    // do something else
}
```

The problem is, that code changes the color of all `<td>` labeled 'pme-cell-WFA' regardless of whether they contain 'Test' or a non-breaking space, or something else entirely.

I've tried a few different ways of doing this but they all either highlight everything yellow, or don't highlight anything at all.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Comment: What are you trying to highlight with this? The cells that don't contain `"Test"`? Because in your `if` you are selecting and coloring all the cells.

Comment: You should use .each() to loop through every td in your table and then evaluate $(this) in your loop. This way you will have reference to the actual culprit.

Comment: Your **title** doesn't ask any question and is meaningless, please rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your one line solution would be something like this:

```
$('.pme-main tr').find('td.pme-cell-WFA:not(:contains("Test"))').css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
```

You can select the other cells by removing the `:not` part.

But if you have a lot of processing you want to do, then you are probably better off selecting the cells and then looping through them, checking the contents of each and doing whatever is appropriate.

For example, something like this:

```js
$('.pme-main tr').find('td.pme-cell-WFA').each(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  if (!$(this).text().includes("Test")) {
    elem.css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
  } else {
    elem.css('backgroundColor', 'red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="pme-main">

  <tr>
    <td class="pme-cell-WFA">Test</td>
    <td class="pme-cell-WFA">Bar</td>
    <td class="pme-cell-WFA">Foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I actually was doing it that way and it worked fine, however it made it difficult do add more 'checks' such as only doing the highlight if the cell to the left has text etc.

Comment: I also tried this and it works. For example I check the TD to the left to see if it is empty (non breaking space) and if it is not empty I change the colors.
$('.pme-main tr').find('td.pme-cell-WFA').each(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  if ((!$(this).prev().text().includes("\xa0")) && (!$(this).text().includes("\xa0"))) {
    elem.css('backgroundColor', '#25f95e');
    elem.prev().css('backgroundColor', '#25f95e');
  }
});

Answer (score 1):

The issue is jQuery returns an object which evaluates to true, even if it didn't find any results.

Check the `length` which returns the number of results.

Also as @Matt Burland points out. You need to apply the CSS to the matching results, not all of them. You can store the results and reuse them like below:

```
var results = $('.pme-main tr').find('td.pme-cell-WFA:not(:contains("Test"))');

if (results.length) {
    results.css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
}
else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: I tried using this code but it does exactly the same thing. It highlights all of the 'pme-cell-WFA' regardless of having Test or not.

Comment: @JasonM: That's because your next line: `$('.pme-main tr').find('td.pme-cell-WFA').css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');` selects all the `.pme-cell-WFA` cells again without regard to whether or not they passed the test in the `if` clause.

Comment: Ok, I didnt realize it did that.  Using the new code you posted I was able to get it working the way I want.   Thanks!